# I copied a form twice, and when I run the program, it says two output file names resolved to the same output path:

Tags: c#, path, output

[image]

I copy the form 1 to and paste it to become form2, and form3 again. But this error appears.

Comment: Your question itself has the answer. Look at the Solution Explorer closely. Under Form2.cs you have linked files, you will see Form1 class there. Fix that and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can't copy them that easily, you need to go to the folder where the forms are in your file explorer (not solution explorer), copy them there, rename them there, then open them up in notepad (not visual studio), now you'll have multiple classes with the same name so you need to change the one mention of the class name at the top of each of the code sheets (notepad still!) and Include those files in your project, and you'll be good to go.

It's not as easy as copy and paste in solution explorer, remove what you've copied and do it inside file explorer.